# What is the network structure of Ademxapp Model A1 Trained on Cityscapes Data in the Mathematica?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-networks, segmentation

I want to implement the model ([Ademxapp Model A1 Trained on Cityscapes Data](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Ademxapp-Model-A1-Trained-on-Cityscapes-Data)) on my data for segmentation, so I need the partial structure of this model, can anyone help?

Comment: Are you asking about the architecture of the net? It's in the link you shared: 
`NetModel["Ademxapp Model A1 Trained on Cityscapes Data"]`

Comment: No, I mean the code used for the model

Comment: You can get the full net graph with `NetInformation[
 NetModel["Ademxapp Model A1 Trained on Cityscapes Data"],"FullSummaryGraphic"]` 

and the type of each layer with `NetInformation[
 NetModel["Ademxapp Model A1 Trained on Cityscapes Data"], "Layers"]`

And then connect together the layers as they are shown in the `"FullSummaryGraphic"`.

I'm not sure how to get the trained parameter values though.

You could also just grab the (python) code [from github](https://github.com/itijyou/ademxapp)

Comment: Thanks for your help